# Problems to get two graphics in different pages with standalone

Tags: pstricks, standalone

In the following MWE I get a single page with the two graphics within:

```
\documentclass[multi]{standalone}

\standaloneenv{pspicture}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, prologue]{xcolor}
\colorlet{BaseColor}{Crimson}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0.5,0.5)
\psline[linecolor = BaseColor](0.5,0.5)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psline(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, I get the graphics split in two pages if I say:

```
\documentclass[pstricks,multi]{standalone}

\standaloneenv{pspicture}
%\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, prologue]{xcolor}
%   \colorlet{BaseColor}{Crimson}
%\usepackage{pstricks}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0.5,0.5)
\psline(0.5,0.5)  % linecolor key not used anymore. See below
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psline(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

My problem about the last MWE is that if I pass the `pstricks` option to `standalone`, there is a clash with the options I need for the `xcolor` package.

I have the same problem (a single page) if I use the option `class =  memoir`.

How can these issues be solved?

EDIT: Well, I solved the problem about the splitting in two pages by just typing the line 
`\standaloneenv{pspicture}` after loading the `pstricks` package, but I do not get any actual graphics on the pdf file either through `dvi -> ps -> pdf` or `dvi -> pdf`. This is due to the `linecolor` I am using.

The problem with `class = memoir` remains, too. I don't get any contents if I use that option -- the pages are there at the correct bounding box sizes, though, but they are empty.

Is it possible to solve these issues?

Comment: Regarding the option clash: [TeX Frequently Asked Questions -- question label "optionclash"](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=optionclash) —> put the options you want to add to `xcolor` into a `\PassOptionsToPackage` command _before_ `\documentclass{standalone}`.

Comment: do you want with `memoir` and without `standalone` also two pages?

Answer (score 4):

```
\RequirePackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, prologue]{xcolor}
\documentclass[multi,pstricks]{standalone}

\colorlet{BaseColor}{Crimson}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0.5,0.5)
\psline[linecolor = BaseColor](0.5,0.5)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psline(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you have `[pstricks]` as optional argument for `standalone` then the package loads `pstricks` and `pstricks` itself `xcolor`. This is the reason why you can't load `xcolor` later with other optional arguments.

With memoir you get only one page:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[dvipsnames, svgnames, prologue]{pstricks}
\colorlet{BaseColor}{Crimson}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(0.5,0.5)
\psline[linecolor = BaseColor](0.5,0.5)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psline(1,1)
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

running it with `pdflatex --shell-escape <file>` will give the expected output.

Answer (score 3):

It takes 257 characters.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,dvipsnames,svgnames,prologue]{standalone}
\colorlet{BaseColor}{Crimson}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(.5,.5)
\psline[linecolor=BaseColor](.5,.5)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psline(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

### The last resort

The following takes 363 characters.

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,prologue]{memoir}
\usepackage{pstricks}

\colorlet{BaseColor}{Crimson}
\usepackage[tightpage,active]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{pspicture}
\PreviewBorder=12pt\relax

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(.5,.5)
\psline[linecolor=BaseColor](.5,.5)
\end{pspicture}
\begin{pspicture}(1,1)
\psline(1,1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Herbert's answer takes 297 characters.

Comment: @{Code Mocker, Herbert}: LOL! Both answers are right, although the first to point out at this was Speravir by means of his comment (I believe it is "his"). Nonetheless, the problem with `class = memoir` remains.

Comment: @Marcos: See my update.

Comment: @Marcos Yepp, you believe right.

Comment: @Speravir: That's what I expected from your profile pic ;-) Now, if you'd only had any hints on why the `class = memoir` option fails, and provided an answer including the "color affair", I think it'd be just fair checking yours.

Comment: @Code Mocker: I appreciate, and it works right. Nonetheless, it is more of a workaround than an answer to the issue with the `class = memoir` option.